# How to use html2canvas on all matching jQuery objects

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

**How can i catch all generated div id's in jquery and generate one image per div id?**

PHP

```
foreach(range(1,$count) as $pin){
            echo "<div class='invite col-lg-6 col-xs-6' id='".$prefix.$pin."'>";
```

JQUERY

```
$(".invite").each(function(i){
            var elm = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(elm);
            var w = "600";
            var h = "300";
            var type = "png";
            var filename = "invite";
            html2canvas(elm).then(function(canvas){
                var canWith = canvas.with;
                var canHeight = canvas.height;
                var img = Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvas, canWith, canHeight);
                Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas, w, h, type, filename);
            });
    });
```

My solution it's not working.
Catches all id's in an array and i cannot catch one id at a time to generate div image using html2canvas lib.

Comment: Pass the element to html2canvas instead of the element's id. (i.e. `var elm = $(this)`)

Comment: The element is a DIV but i have many more divs below that one. html2canvas needs to know what element must render as image. Am i wrong?

Comment: html2canvas outputs that elelemt is not in DOM. Uncaught (in promise) Provided element is not within a Document

Comment: The `$('.invite')` creates an array of all "invite" div elements, and `.each()` passes each one into the function you have defined. So the function will run one-by-one over each "invite".

Comment: I wish :) but sadly the each function is passing an object... i thionk i must loop that object.

Comment: It's because `html2canvas` doesn't like jQuery objects, so try `var elm = $(this).get(0);` to retrieve the DOM object from within the jQuery object.

Comment: With get(0) it only converts to image the last div.

Comment: Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/rn58tvse/

Comment: Yes. It works in fiddle, bit with html2canvas it outoputs (index):1 Uncaught (in promise) Provided element is not within a Document

Answer (score -1):

You're iterating through `.invite` using `each` so you must get different IDs but not all. So, here's no any issue at all. However, I can see some issues in your code example:

1. It should have `width` not `with`.
2. It should save as different filename but not the same. You're just saving the file as `filename` and you're overriding the file with last one.
3. You should pass the element not element's id in the `html2canvas`.
4. Also, pass the `type` in convertToImage`

So, it should have no issue:

```
$(".invite").each(function(i){
  var elem = $(this);
  var elemId = elem.attr('id');
  var w = "600";
  var h = "300";
  var type = "png";
  var filename = "invite";
  html2canvas(elem).then(function(canvas){
    var canWidth = canvas.width;
    var canHeight = canvas.height;
    var img = Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvas, canWidth, canHeight, type);
    Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas, w, h, type, filename + '-' + elemId);
  });
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. i can make it to work converting jquery object to loop and then iterating, but it only saves first and last div as images. Perhaps due to lack of time generating middle divs?